# Querying non-SQL multidimensional store

Tags: olap, mondrian

I have a data store with multidimensional arrays, which I would like to expose to Mondrian. Is it correct that as for now Monrian can only work with SQL databases?

My arrays are rather small so I can comfortably load them into memory - perhaps I can somehow populate the Mondrian cache with them within my dialect implementation? This way Mondrian would never have to issue any SQL queries as all data would be loaded into the cache.

Is this doable and can existing API be used for it or would I have to change some core Mondrian classes to implement it?